# Calculating accuracy if experimental value overshoots actual value?

Tags: python, math

I've looked at the accuracy formula and it looks like this:

```
e_value = 400
t_value = 1000

accuracy = ((t_value - e_value)/t_value) * 100
```

And this works as expected (40%).

What if `e_value` is much bigger than the t_value though?

In my case for example, my `e_value` is `18` while the `t_value` is `2`.

The accuracy should (?) be a very low number as `18` is 9 times `2`, but the number we get if we plug in the numbers is `-800%` which doesn't really seem right (and also, it's not really what I'm after, I want a number between 0-100%)

Comment: What would you expect the accuracy to be in your example, and why?

Comment: You're probably looking for absolute error, such that both over and underestimations return the same error.

Comment: The formula is correct and [negative values can be useful](https://sciencing.com/calculate-percent-accuracy-6199228.html). Regarding the big percentage, it can change depending on the units you use. For example, if you are using celcius and t_value is 0 degrees, the formula doesn't produce meaningful errors. You should instead work with units which makes the measures makes things more linear with a meaningful zero-point (For example, use Kelvin for temperatures). It all depends on the nature of the data.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé the data is quite literally 'internet points'. I am doing something similar to Machine Learning and I wanted to track the accuracy of the 'model' I'm training.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of question is best asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/ but ...

Assuming `t_value` is fixed you want a function where

`f(e_value) → 0` as `e_value →  ± ∞` and

`f(t_value) = 1`

This suggests using a function like `exp(-(t_value-e_value)^2)`

This is a version of a Gaussian normal curve (bell shape) - think of what a histogram of heights for a large number of people would look like. This is related to probability theory so you can think of probability of be within a range as the area under the bell curve graph between these two vertical lines (if you make the total area under curve 1 by dividing by `sqrt(pi)`)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution